# Page freezes when running process in background with suckerpunch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sucker-punch

i try to start a process in the background which executes some code. When i start the process, my app freezes until the background task is done. Iam using SuckerPunch to work around exactly this freezing, however the app still waits for the process to end. Do i have the wrong expectations ? How can i solve it ?

app/controller/mycontroller:

```
MyJob.perform_async(data_array)
```

app/jobs/myjob:

```
class MyClass

    include SuckerPunch::Job
    workers 1

    def perform(data)
        my code which takes around 20sec to execute
    end
end
```

Comment: my bad, i handed over the wrong arguments.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider deleting the question.